# Nservicebus Singleton pattern - hook into currently existing objects

Tags: singleton, nservicebus

I am working through the first steps of figuring out Nservicebus and planning a reasonably large scale (at least for me) app.

I want the app to be able to scale out onto X machines.  It will have a number of services, such as:

LogonService
UserManagementService
GameService
RoomService
etc...

The clients would talk to the server through WCF.  The services themselves would talk to each other via NServiceBus and MSMQ.  [Sacha Barber has written an excellent article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/nserviceBusDemo.aspx) on getting started with NServiceBus and has come up against the same situation I am going to hit.  There is a further chat between Udi and Sacha about this [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/8575).

My Question is, when a service is handling a message how does it know about the rest of the app in that service? As Sacha puts it, "a handler will automagically" appear when a message needs dealing with.  So when this is created how does it know about the other objects that are already up and running.  For example in the GameService, it would have a list of all games currently running.  How would it access this?

I guess the two options that I can think of, (as Sacha pointed out), are:

Mediator pattern
Singleton

Out of the two I think I would rather register a singleton with Castle Windsor and use it that way.

Is this an appropriate use of the Singleton pattern, (as you often see people referring to the Singleton as the "Devil", I don't want to miss use it if possible).

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For state that need to be kept in memory I would also use the Singleton pattern. Otherwise state is usually maintained in the datastore and read by the handler for each message proceed.

```
public Handle(SomeMessage msg)
{
   var aggregateRoot = writeStore.Get(msg.SomeId);

   aggregate.DoSomeAction(msg.SomeOtherData);

   //if write store does not support dirty tracking
   writeStore.Save(aggregateRoot);
}
```

Comment: Cool, that's how I feel about it as well. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are pretty awful if you want to do unit tests among other things.  NServiceBus uses Spring (by default) as a dependency injection framework when initialising the message handlers.  Ideally, you'd plug into Spring yourself and register your objects so they can be injected via. spring.

Having said that, Singletons are an easy way to achieve what you want.  However if the only reason you'd be making an object a singleton is for NServiceBus to access it, I'd suggest finding a better way to do it.

Comment: Hi Mrnye, thanks for the comment. Do you have any suggestions on how NServiceBus could get the same instance of an object out each time a message is received without a singleton?  The reason being it will already have state and currently running processes that the message will need to interact with.  i am not going direct to a db or the like. Thanks again.

Comment: As I mentioned, you have to use a dependency injection framework.  NServiceBus uses Spring.Net by default (see http://www.springframework.net/).  I haven't used it before, so you will have to work out how to register objects with spring.  When you get that working, you just declare a public property `public IBus { get; set; }` and Spring will see this and automatically populate it with the instance of the class.  Read up on spring and dependency injection to learn more

Comment: Yep, I am using Castle instead of Spring, normally you register a Type of class and it creates a new instance of that class when you need it.  I need it to return the single instance of a class becuase it is already running.  As I understand it registering the running class with the IOC framework is the same as the singleton pattern, am I missing something?